# Gmail API returns "Delegation denied for my.email@email.com" when setting a different email as recipient

Tags: kotlin, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API to create drafts.
When I create a draft message where the recipient is my own email (the one that generates the credential), everything works fine but when I try to use a different email, the following message is printed:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Delegation denied for my.email.here@gmail.com",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Delegation denied for my.email.here@gmail.com",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
```

That's how I'm assembling my `MimeMessage`:

```kotlin
val props = Properties()
val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
val message = MimeMessage(session)
message.setFrom(message.sender)
message.addRecipient(JavaxMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress("different.email.here@gmail.com"))
message.subject = subject
```

The scopes I am using:

```
// "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose"
GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE
```

I've tried a lot of stuff to make it work, but I didn't have any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Delegation denied for my.email.here@gmail.com

This email appears to be a standard gmail email address.   You appear to be trying to delegate a service account to a user with a standard gmail email address.

Service accounts only work with google workspace email accounts. You need to set up domain wide delegation to the serveries account and then you can set the delegation user.

If you want to use a standard gmail account you will need to authorize the user using Oauth2.

```
private fun getCredentials(httpTransport: NetHttpTransport): Credential? {
    val inputStream = File("credentials.json").inputStream()
    val clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, InputStreamReader(inputStream))
    val flow = GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory(File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build()
    val receiver = LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build()
    return AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user")
}



 public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                          String from,
                                          String subject,
                                          String bodyText)
            throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }
```

[Sending](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#java)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't quite understand this part: "Service accounts only work with google workspace email accounts. You need to set up domain wide delegation to the serveries account and then you can set the delegation user.", How can I do it? Am I required to have a web domain? Thanks again :D

Comment: Google [workspace](https://workspace.google.com/) is the new name for GSuite.  Its a group of tools for businesses.   You are required to have a workspace account if you want to use service accounts with gmail it only works with the email accounts on that domain.    You cant use it with normal user accounts.

Comment: Hmmm. So it's not as easy as one think to create a draft email with a  "random" recipient email :/. Knowing that, Do you know if it is possible to retrieve the user email from "Gmail" object (the one that authorized the app)?

Comment: I've just realized how. I was forgetting to use `execute()`: gmail.users().getProfile("me").execute().emailAddress

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DaImTo for your reply and all the info provided.

---

Based on the info provided, to those who have the same problem as I do, I've found a nice workaround:

- set the "TO" recipient to the user's email;
- add a "BCC" recipient to the actual recipient email.

Here's the code to demonstrate it:

```
    val meProfile = gmail.users().getProfile("me").execute()
    val toRecipient = InternetAddress(meProfile.emailAddress)
    val ccRecipient = InternetAddress(to)

    val props = Properties()
    val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
    val message = MimeMessage(session)
    message.setFrom(message.sender)

    // here's the magic :D
    message.addRecipient(JavaxMessage.RecipientType.TO, toRecipient)
    message.addRecipient(JavaxMessage.RecipientType.BCC, ccRecipient)

    message.subject = subject
```